# Can personal banking customers use the BMO Harris Bank remote cheque deposit system?

Tags: canada, check, online-banking, deposits

I live in Canada. I notice that BMO Harris Bank offers [remote cheque deposit software](https://dm2.midepositedge.com/), powered by DepositEdge, for its commercial banking customers. But I only have a personal banking account with BMO.

As a personal banking customer with Bank of Montreal, can I still use their remote deposit capture software?

Comment: Consider Tangerine or CIBC for a smartphone cheque deposit feature if that would satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I did a bit more research and found out that BMO Harris Bank is a US bank. So I doubt their remote deposit capture system won't work in Canada.